# Updating entries on Firebase (redux-react)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I am stuck around a project and honestly I don't know how to solve it (I am quite new before you judge)

so this is my code:

```
class EditProfile extends Component {
  state = {
    företagsnamn: '',
    organisationsnummer: '',
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
  };
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(this.state);
    this.props.editProfile(this.state);
    this.props.history.push("/dash");
  };
  render() {
    const { auth, profile } = this.props;
    if (auth.isEmpty) return <Redirect to="/dash" />;
    return (
      <div >        
        <form className="white" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col xl6 l6 m6 s12">
 <label>Foretagsnamn:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            disabled
            placeholder={profile.foretagsnamn}
            id="foretagsnamn"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            </div>
            <div className="col xl6 l6 m6 s12">
            <label>organisationsnummer:</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            placeholder={profile.organisationsnummer}
            id="organisationsnummer"
            onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            </div>
            </div>


<div className="input-field">
          <button className="btn orange lighten-1" style={{width:'100%'}} >Submit</button>
          { }
        </div>
          </form>
</div>
}}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    auth: state.firebase.auth,
    profile: state.firebase.profile
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    editProfile: profil => dispatch(editProfile(profil))
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(EditProfile);
```

this was the action

```
export const editProfile = (profil) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirestore, getFirebase }) => {
        const firebase = getFirebase();
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        const profile = getState().firebase.auth
        console.log(profile)
        const authorId = getState().firebase.auth.uid;
        // const foretagsnamn = getFirestore().firestore.collection('users').doc(profile.uid).foretagsnamn
        // firebase.auth()
      firestore.collection('users').doc(profile.uid).set({
            // foretagsnamn: foretagsnamn,
            // organisationsnummer: profil.organisationsnummer,
            adress: profil.adress,
            ort: profil.ort,
            telefonnummer: profil.telefonnummer,
            postnummer: profil.postnummer, 

        }, { merge: true }
        ).then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_SUCCESS' });
          }).catch(err => {
            dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_ERROR' }, err);
          });
        }}
```

and this the reducer

```
 const editProfileReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "EDITPROFILE_ERROR":
        return {
          ...state,
        editError: action.error
    };
    case "EDITPROFILE_SUCCESS":
        return {
          ...state,
          user:action.user

    };
      default:
      return state;
    }
  }

  export default editProfileReducer;
```

however when I press the button submit it shows this error:

> FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined

**PS: Solved. The action was wrong. I changed** ´´´const profile = getState().firebase.auth.```**instead of profile. **

Stays open if someone needs.

Comment: can you change .add to .set in





     {          firestore.collection('users').doc(profile.uid).add({
            ...profil
         })               }

and if there is still error give a screenshot?

Comment: ×
FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined

Comment: Gives the same error .set same error.

Comment: can you console log { profile } one line after it created?

Comment: shows the entries already existent in the database

Comment: hey @Oblicion A are you still having an issue or where you able to fix it?

Comment: However [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.html#doc) is the reference for the CollectionReference method for Firestore.